# What is the best way of presenting many Bar Chart plots

Tags: r, data-visualization, histogram

I used R programming to produce separate 30 Bar Chart plots. The x-axis scale is the same for the 30 plots (11 bins), but y-axis is different.

I want to present these results in a limited work of pages.

Is there a way, for example, a plot or any ideas that could help me to present the results instead of those 30 plots.

Comment: Please explain what is plotted on the x-axis and what is plotted on the y-axis.  What role do "bins" have for plotting bar charts?  Indeed, could you state what you mean by a "bar chart"?  Are you using that as a synonym for "histogram" (which it is not)?

Comment: Can you post example data for people to work with? You can get really nice answers that way. You also need to provide some context, eg, what the variables mean & what you want to learn from them / show about them.

Answer (score 0):

Make 30 different plots, assign them each to their own object. Then arrange them in a 6 by 5 grid using `gridExtra::grid.arrange()` or `cowplot::plot_grid()`

Comment: This would be a great answer if the question were posted on [SO], but here we are expecting answers that address the second part of the question: "any ideas that could help me to present the results *instead* of those 30 plots.".